# group and aggregate with rxjs

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rxjs

Scan works like this(with sum function):

```
1-1-1-1-1-1 -> 1-2-3-4-5-6
```

but I need something like this: with n=3

```
1-1-1-1-1-1 -> 3-3
```

How do I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RxJs you can use `bufferWithCount`:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.from([1,1,1,1,1,1])
                  .bufferWithCount(3)
                  .flatMap(group => Rx.Observable.from(group).sum());
```

You could optionally use `windowWithCount` so that you don't have to rewrap the output in order to use `sum` but you'll also get an empty final window as well, which will fire out an extraneous 0 value.

Comment: in the last line, instead of returning a stream and doing a flatmap, couldn't you just return the sum of the group and do a map outside?

Comment: @tldr you certainly could, the buffers are just arrays, as I far as I know though you would have to roll your own `sum` method using something like `Array.prototype.reduce`. Trivial perhaps, but it seemed easier to just use the built in RxJS operator.

Answer (score 1):

This works in c#:

```
var query =
    new [] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, }
        .ToObservable()
        .Buffer(3)
        .Select(x => x.Sum());
```

I assume [rxjs] would work similarly.